# Spring MVC return several objects in one request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, request

In my controller i have these ff  methods

```
  @RequestMapping("/countryList.html")
  @ModelAttribute("countries")
  public Collection<Country> getCountries() {
    return worldService.getAllCountries();
  }

  @RequestMapping("/countryList.html")
  public String getName() {
    return viewers_name;
  }
```

What I was trying to do is that in the countryList.html, it will return the countries and the name of the current user viewing it, however upon accessing the countryList.html it returned me an exception

```
Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path '/countryList.html': {public java.lang.String levelup.world.web.CountryController.getName(), public java.util.Collection levelup.world.web.CountryController.getCountries()}.
```

How would I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@RequestMapping("/countryList.html")** should be unique to mehod. How you gave this request mapping to two methods.

As Per your comments:-

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/countryList.html")
public Collection<Country> getCountries(ModelMap model) {     
        model.addAttribute("countries", countryObject);
   return viewName;

     }
```

**Or define jsonView in config to return json object for ajax calls**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/countryList.html")
public Collection<Country> getCountries(ModelMap model) {     
        model.addAttribute("countries", countryObject);
   return jsonView;

     }
```

Comment: Does spring automatically pass the ModelMap? my countries is a type list, does spring automatically detects that on the view?

Answer (score 2):

Because You have the same request mapping to different methods. The exception message is simple

Comment: But on the view I want it to have the countries and name. how would I resolve that?

Comment: It should be defined in one method, one solution Your method can also be annotated with @ResponseBody. You can return in that body both country list and the user name. Read about this annotation, You can return it even in JSON format